# Need some clarification on how the state pattern works

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-pattern

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Machine
{
  class State *current;
  public:
    Machine();
    void setCurrent(State *s)
    {
        current = s;
    }
    void on();
    void off();
};

class State
{
  public:
    virtual void on(Machine *m)
    {
        cout << "   already ON\n";
    }
    virtual void off(Machine *m)
    {
        cout << "   already OFF\n";
    }
};

void Machine::on()
{
  current->on(this);
}

void Machine::off()
{
  current->off(this);
}

class ON: public State
{
  public:
    ON()
    {
        cout << "   ON-ctor ";
    };
    ~ON()
    {
        cout << "   dtor-ON\n";
    };
    void off(Machine *m);
};

class OFF: public State
{
  public:
    OFF()
    {
        cout << "   OFF-ctor ";
    };
    ~OFF()
    {
        cout << "   dtor-OFF\n";
    };
    void on(Machine *m)
    {
        cout << "   going from OFF to ON";
        m->setCurrent(new ON());
        delete this;
    }
};

void ON::off(Machine *m)
{
  cout << "   going from ON to OFF";
  m->setCurrent(new OFF());
  delete this;
}

Machine::Machine()
{
  current = new OFF();
  cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  void(Machine:: *ptrs[])() = 
  {
    Machine::off, Machine::on
  };
  Machine fsm;
  int num;
  while (1)
  {
    cout << "Enter 0/1: ";
    cin >> num;
    (fsm. *ptrs[num])();
  }
}
```

There are a few bits of code I don't completely understand.

First, what does this do exactly?

```
(fsm. *ptrs[num])();
```

It looks like it's calling a default constructor of state, but I am not totally sure. Also, I don't understand where the on and off method is called. I think the object machine is the calling object for the on and off method, but I am not even sure.

Lastly, why do we destroy this?

```
void on(Machine *m)
{
    cout << "   going from OFF to ON";
    m->setCurrent(new ON());
    delete this;
}
```

Is it only for memory management?

Comment: ptrs is an array of function pointers, that you have initialized to thepublic off and on functions of the Machine class. So, in the while loop, based on the number, you input the code (fsm.*ptrs[num])() will call the function on fsm object. ie., for 0 it will call off() and 1 it wil call on()

Comment: could you rewrite the code to make it easier to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten the code with two function pointers and some comments:
Instead of array of function pointers, I have used 2 diff pointers and I am using if else for making the decision for switching state.

Main:

```
int main()
{
  void (Machine::*offptr)() = &Machine::off;    //offptr is a member funct pointer that now points to Machine::off function
  void (Machine::*onptr)() = &Machine::on;      //onptr is a member funct pointer that now points to Machine::on function
  Machine fsm;
  int num;
  while (1)
  {
      cout<<"Enter 0/1: ";
      cin>>num;
      if( num == 0 )
      {
          (fsm.*offptr)();          //Here your are calling the function pointed to by the offptr (i.e., Machine::off) using the pointer
      }
      else if( num == 1 )
      {
          (fsm.*onptr)();           //Here your are calling the function pointed to by the onptr (i.e., Machine::on) using the pointer
      }
  }

}
```

In your example, all the decision is taken with the help of pointer array indices it self. So if user presses 0 the function pointed by `ptrs[0]` will be called and for 1 the function pointed by `ptr[1]` will be called. But since there is no check to make sure the user entered 0/1, the program will crash if the user enters something other than 0 or 1.

```
void on(Machine *m)
{
    cout << "   going from OFF to ON";
    m->setCurrent(new ON());    //Here you are changing the state of the machine from OFF to ON (Note: call comes to this function only if the previous state was OFF).
    delete this;                //The previous state instance (OFF state pointed by this pointer) of the machine is no more required. So you are deleting it.
}
```